# What is the difference between entropy and deviance?

Tags: data-mining, cart

In terms of classification task using decision trees, the formula for these looks almost the same. So, how are they different/same? what is the purpose of each in terms of impurity measure?

$\text{Entropy}~(p_1,p_2) = -\sum p_i \log (p_i);  i= 1,2;$

$p_i $ are fractions. Say, if I have 2 Yes and 3 No in a node, $p_1=2/5$, $p_2=3/5$.

$\text{Deviance}~D= - 2\sum n_k \log(p_k) ;~k $ is the class in each leaf.

Both are used as impurity measures. But I am not able to understand the difference between these.

Comment: And can you provide the three formulas you are referring to (Entropy, Deviance, Impurity measure)? There are more then one.

Comment: Clarification please: This formulas relate to _each leaf_ separately? If yes, I guess in each leaf we have "k" possible outcomes, each with count "n_k" in this leaf, and each with empirical relative frequency "p_k" in the specific leaf? If not, please clarify.

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 4):

They are same. It's a nomenclature difference among authors. Gini is different though. Using your notation it would be $1 - \sum p_i^2$.

Comment: Could you please show the formulas for deviance and entropy are the same? They seem like slightly different formulas at first glance